# AutoFixture Likeness - compare only matching properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I want to be able to compare the two following objects for likeness using AutoFixture.SemanticComparison:

```
public class Object1
{
  public int a;
}

public class Object2
{
  public int a;
  public int b;
}
```

Now, when I do it this way:

```
var o1 = new Object1 { a = 1 };
var o2 = new Object2 { a = 1, b = 2};
o1.AsSource().OfLikeness<Object2>().ShouldEqual(o2);
```

I get the following exception: "The following members did not match: - b."

I found out that I can omit the 'b' member like this:

```
var o1 = new Object1 { a = 1 };
var o2 = new Object2 { a = 1, b = 2};
o1.AsSource().OfLikeness<Object2>().Without(object2 => object2.b).ShouldEqual(o2);
```

However, I find that this is quite cumbersome, because whenever I add a new member to class Object2, I have to correct my unit tests (or at least unit test helpers).

Is there a way to say "I want to compare for likeness just for the subset that exists in both objects"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to compare two objects based on the **intersection** of their properties. This is not currently supported by the Likeness class. The reasoning is this:

Right now the destination type (in the above example, that would be Object2) is the decisive template upon which matching is done. This provides quite a *strong* statement for an assertion: *every public property or field of this class must be matched.*

However, a statement about matching the intersection of properties would be a very *weak* statement, because that **intersection might be empty**. This could result in [False Negatives](http://xunitpatterns.com/false%20negative.html).

Even if you are TDDing and following the Red/Green/Refactor cycle and you've seen a unit test failing with such a hypothetical Likeness intersection, subsequent refactorings might turn such an assertion into a False Negative, as you remove the last property or field the two objects have in common - and you'll never notice.

However, AutoFixture is open source and all, so you're welcome to [suggest this feature](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues) or send a pull request.

Comment: The argument you described is quite strong. It led me into thinking about what is more cumbersome - adding new properties to Without() or tracking the two objects for property names changes to avoid false positives.
Thanks for turning my attention to this!